# Scientific studies on methods to improve pushups?

Tags: push-ups

There are about as many "methods" to improve pushups as are there web pages that talk about improving pushups. Most of these are "it worked for us" and "seems common sense" types of methods.

What does the science say? What scientific studies are out there that compare an measure different ways to improve pushups?

Comment: Cant speak for a push-up specific study but greasing the groove is a tried and tested and proven method to improve aptitude at a specific activity. Physical Fitness studies have always said the same thing: **Do lots of X to get good at doing X, Y may help improve X but practicing X takes precedent.** http://breakingmuscle.com/learn/greasing-the-groove-how-to-make-it-work-for-you

Comment: @Pihrew are you looking for improvement in weighted pushups or a higher rep count? And why would you look at a pushup as different than any other strength exercise? There's nothing fundamentally different about training for increases in the bench press (either in max or endurance) than there would be for pushups.

Answer (score 1):

There are +1000 studies that have the keyword push up in them-on PubMed. A reliable site that gathers studies in the fields of medicine/health/exercices/supplements/...

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/?term=push-up

But honestly, this is an easy exercise to build up(and imo one of the most fun ones). Just be sure to use proper technique(body straight, and go down with your arms, not your belly/legs/...) Most of the basic rosters out there will help, even of you find 5 different ones. They will most likely all work for a beginner.

You'll also begin to feel for yourself after a while what you're capable of and what method works best for you.